# SWF transcoding, does it exist?

Tags: java, encoding, flash, transcoding

I am looking for some type of SWF transcoder so I can convert SWF files to .avi's. Preferably something that we could hook into our Java architecture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to convert videos from a location like you-tube or are you trying to turn what the SWF would be showing in to a avi for like a demo purpose? Videos from places like youtube are not stored in the SWF file, that is just a player that is streaming another file (usualy h.264 encoded) from another location.

Comment: I am trying to convert SWF's to a video format that could be uploaded to youTube. This is part of a web application so a desktop SWF to flv conveter does not meet my needs unless it can also be run headless via command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bit like: I am looking for some type of java binaries transcoder, that can transcode java binaries to HTML+JS. Preferably something that we could hook into our PHP architecture. :P

let me explain: SWF files are containers to AVM/AVM2 bytecode and different kinds of assets (text, video, audio, raw binary data). It is possible to create SWF files containing ONLY bytecode or SWF files containing only media. Only in the latter case is the course of all playback determined. If there is bytecode included, then the task can be very hard, if not impossible, since any visual changes in the flash application can depend on external data, user input or just be random.

also, please note that the resulting AVI is likely to be orders of magnitude bigger.
I guess the easiest and most accurate way is to run the SWF and capture what the flash player renders.

there is no straight-forward way to achieve what you want to. to my knowledge the tools within the creative suite are the only ones that can convert SWF animation into movies.

Comment: haha thanks for being helpful and making me laugh at the same time! I was really hoping that wasn't the case, but at the same time expecting it to be.